# AzureEventhub python sdk - greenthreads & os-threads

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, azure-eventhub, eventlet

Working in a large code base that is based on eventlet and greenthreads; trying to integrate with `azure-eventhub` python library which internally spawns `threading.Thread` to consume events and trigger callbacks.

When starting the consumer, the main app (which has multiple other greenthreads) hangs, also consumer starts but `on_event` callback does not trigger even when events are pushed (but on KeyboardInterrupt it prints few of the expected messages).
Running the same consumer code in a standalone script works.

What I've tried:

- eventlet.monkey_patch()
- spawn a greenthread which runs `consumer.start`
- spawn a `multiprocessing.Process` which runs `consumer.start`

I'm aware that eventlet does not play well with `os threads` or `mp`, and indeed none of those worked.
A working solution is based on `subprocess.Popen`, but I rather find another approach.

OS ubuntu.18.04
python 3.8.16
eventlet 0.32.0
greenlet 1.0.0

Is there a way to patch the specific function call for `threading.Thread` inside `consumer.start`? or any other suggestions are welcome.

edit: the consumer code is a basic example in the [azure eventhub repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/recv.py)